# Set MDC value before any logging and retain until logging is completed

Tags: dynamic, mdc

I have Logback configuration with SiftingAppender where dynamic MDC value is set on application load in main() method which is generated dynamically. How can I ensure that MDC value generated from Java code is loaded before all logging is started in any class? Because when I start log in SingletonUUID class it logs to directory "default" (default value of SiftAppender discriminator).

Here is my logback.xml:

```
<property name="LocalDevLogLevel" value="INFO" />
<property name="log-dir" value="simple-service-log" />

<property name="COMMON_LOG_PATTERN" value="%-30([%thread]) %-5level - %logger{32} - %msg%n"/>

<appender name="simpleConsole" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS 'UTC'", UTC} ${COMMON_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="SIFTSYSLOG" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
    <discriminator>
        <key>serviceInstanceId</key>
        <defaultValue>default</defaultValue>
    </discriminator>
    <sift>
        <appender name="FILE-${serviceInstanceId}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <file>./${log-dir}/${serviceInstanceId}/sys.log</file>
            <append>false</append>
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                <pattern>%d{"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS 'UTC'", UTC} ${COMMON_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
            </layout>

            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
                <FileNamePattern>./${log-dir}/${serviceInstanceId}/sys.%i.log.zip</FileNamePattern>
                <MinIndex>1</MinIndex>
                <MaxIndex>10</MaxIndex>
            </rollingPolicy>

            <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
                <MaxFileSize>10MB</MaxFileSize>
            </triggeringPolicy>
        </appender>
    </sift>
</appender>

<!--DEVELOPMENT logger-->
<springProfile name="local-dev">
    <logger name="com.simple.service.app" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="SIFTSYSLOG" />
        <appender-ref ref="simpleConsole" />
    </logger>
    <root level="${LocalDevLogLevel}" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="SIFTSYSLOG" />
        <appender-ref ref="simpleConsole" />
    </root>
</springProfile>
```

Main Class:

```
package com.simple.service.app;

import org.slf4j.MDC;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

import com.simple.service.config.MyAppConfig;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class MyApp {
    private static SingletonUUID singletonUUID = SingletonUUID.getInstance();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MDC.put("serviceInstanceId", singletonUUID.getUUID().toString()); // set UUID for log directory
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

SingletonUUID class:

```
package com.simple.service.app;

import java.util.UUID;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class SingletonUUID {

     private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SingletonUUID.class);
     private static SingletonUUID instance = new SingletonUUID();

     private UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

     private SingletonUUID() {
        log.info("SingletonUUID : Initializing instance with UUID : " + uuid.toString());
     }

     public static SingletonUUID getInstance() {
        return instance;
     }

     public UUID getUUID() {
        return this.uuid;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using in main() MDC.put(), I extended Discriminator used this class in logback-spring.xml and removed logging in singletonUUID class.

Extract of logback-spring.xml:

```
    <appender name="SIFTSYSLOG" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
    <discriminator class="com.simple.entity.app.UniqueIdDiscriminator" />
    <sift>
        <appender name="FILE-${serviceInstanceId}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <file>./${log-dir}/${serviceInstanceId}/sys.log</file>
            <append>false</append>
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                <pattern>%d{"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS 'UTC'", UTC} ${COMMON_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
            </layout>

            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
                <FileNamePattern>./${log-dir}/${serviceInstanceId}/sys.%i.log.zip</FileNamePattern>
                <MinIndex>1</MinIndex>
                <MaxIndex>10</MaxIndex>
            </rollingPolicy>

            <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
                <MaxFileSize>10MB</MaxFileSize>
            </triggeringPolicy>
        </appender>
    </sift>
</appender>
```

UniqueIdDiscriminator class:

```
package com.simple.entity.app;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.core.sift.Discriminator;

public class UniqueIdDiscriminator implements Discriminator<ILoggingEvent> {

private static SingletonUUID singletonUUID = SingletonUUID.getInstance();

private static final String KEY = "serviceInstanceId";

private boolean started;

public String getDiscriminatingValue(ILoggingEvent iLoggingEvent) {
    return singletonUUID.getUUID().toString();
}

public String getKey() {
    return KEY;
}

public void start() {
    started = true;
}

public void stop() {
    started = false;
}

public boolean isStarted() {
    return started;
}

}
```